# Does Elastic Search support hot config reloads?

Tags: elasticsearch

Can elasticsearch reload its config without dropping requests?

similar to how nginx supports the SIGHUP signal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know you cannot "reload" the config like you want. But I suppose you need some changes in your configuration and most of them can be done via API (that don't require restarting the service). I would take a look at these links:

[Admin indices update settings](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html)

[Admin cluster update settings](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-update-settings.html)

Comment: Exactly, there are only a few configuration settings needed on file system, the rest is all exposed via REST api.

Comment: other config(like WORK_DIR) change must restart?